# Simple login validator - answered by Krishna Prashatt & phuzi

Tags: javascript, function, object

I am trying to make a simple login validating function. But I got stuck.

[This is the code that I have write](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAfxV.png)
[This is the error text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmM8s.png)

```js
let userLogin = {
  userName: 'fadil',
  password: 'baratestar',
  roll: 'admin'
}

let logIn = function(uName, uPassword) {
  if (uName === userLogin.userName && uPassword === userLogin.password) {
    console.log(`Hi ${uName}! Welcome back and have a nice day.`)
  } else {
    console.log('You entered wrong credentials. Pleas try agin.')
  }
}

logIn('fadil', 'bombastik')
logIn('fadil', 'baratestar')
```

Comment: I am getting the error as `Uncaught ReferenceError: fadil is not defined`. You should be passing the parameters as a string and not as variables.

Comment: `logIn('fadil', 'bombastik')`<br>
`logIn('fadil', 'baratestar')`

Comment: Thank you @Krishna Prashatt & phuzi  for your fast answers. I forgot to pass it in as string. it is fixed now thanks to you. But can you post this solution as a answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @FadilAlFarhan, these are minor mistakes, I do not see any point in posting it as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

For function declaration, you can use like

`function logIn(username, password)....`

And not using let

Comment: Please test your solution before actually posting it as an answer.